# newline is not detected while taking input in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and trying to take characters as input until user enters a newline. My sample code is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>c;
        if(c=='\n')
        {
             cout<<"Newline";
             break;

        }
    }

}
```

The problem is loop is not breaking after pressing enter key of keyboard. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Instead of `cin >> c;` (which skips whitespace) use `cin.get(c)` which reads a character but doesn't skip whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

By default all input using the overloaded `>>` operator *skips* any kind of white-space. If you want to read white-space use the [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) manipulator (or set the appropriate stream flag).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that I think will work for you:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

bool treat_line(std::istream& is)
{
    char c;
    while(is)
    {
        is >> std::noskipws >> c;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
             std::cout << "Newline\n";
             break;
        }
        else
            std::cout << c;
    }
    return bool(is);  // convert "OK" state of stream to boolean
}

int main()
{
    while(treat_line(std::cin))
        ;
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

However, what it seems you want to do is treat data "a line at a time". There is already a function for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while(std::cin)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "handing line: " << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a647d668172265

Answer (score 0):

**getline** option can be used. getline is a standard library function provided in c++ to read a string or a line from input stream.

Syntax: 
**istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);**

is - It is an object of istream class.

str - It is the destination variable , where the input is stored.

**sample Program:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
    string str; 

    cout << "Please enter your name: \n"; 
    getline (cin, str); 
    cout << "Hello, " << str ; 

    return 0; 
}
```

To get the multiple line of input. For instance the below program can be used to get four lines of user input.

```
// A simple C++ program to show working of getline 
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    string str; 
    int t = 4; 
    while (t--) 
    { 
        // Read a line from standard input in str 
        getline(cin, str); 
        cout << str << " : newline" << endl; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```